# React Landing Page render time is too slow. What can I do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance, components

I'm having a problem with a web site that I made with React. It's just a simple landing page where each section is a component and the structure looks like this:

[image]

(I use a provider to change globally the language with an onClick function)

The thing is that while the page runs smooth on a desktop, in mobile the site feels really laggy when I scroll down. I tested the app with React Profiler and get a render time of 30ms which I guess is pretty bad (I read the normal is below 16ms).

The curious thing is that even deleting all the components from the App component, I keep getting at least 20ms of render time. What can I do?

This is the website: https://fondarestaurante.com/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Images of code are not searchable, can not be copied by someone working on the problem, and are not accessible. Please [edit] the question to replace or augment the image with the text that it contains.

Comment: https://github.com/Bruss047/resto this is the repository.